# How to hide elements without having them take space on the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `visibility:hidden` to hide certain elements, but they still take up space on the page while hidden.

How can I make them totally disappear visually, as though they are not in the DOM at all (but without actually removing them from the DOM)?

Comment: This question is very dead, but I'm adding a comment because I recently found myself in a situation that others might experience. I needed to hide an element and **have it retain its `offsetTop`**, and `display:none` would set the `offsetTop` to 0. My solution here was to use `visibility: hidden` then set the width and height to 0. Once I needed to make the element visible again, I removed the three attributes using Javascript. A bit of a hacky solution, but it works well for pretty much all use cases.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Try setting `display:none` to hide and set `display:block` to show.

Comment: its not possible to remove element from dom man. by using this option also. read the question

Comment: not all items should be `display: block`, some will have to be set to `display: inline` (such as `<span>` or `<a>` or `<img>` DOM elements).

Comment: @pranay the question says to hide them not to remove them from the DOM.

Comment: @pranay: The question is not very well expressed but Huusom is solving the problem the user is having.

Comment: @ripper234: sorry. Didn't mean to be rude :-(. I tried to say that your idea seemed to be hiding the element and avoid taking the space. You didn't care if the element was removed or not of the DOM.

Comment: @Claudio - no offence taken :) Cheers.

Comment: And using this property you also cause flickering on iOS Safari ..... it's better to use `visibility` in combination with something else

Comment: An improvement: create a CSS class called `hidden` with `display: none`. Add the class to an element to hide it, remove it show. When removing it, the `display` property is restored to the element default.

Comment: A problem with this solution is that when using `nth-of-type`, given element will still be there resulting in difficulty when making use of this CSS feature in some cases.

Answer (score 50):

use style instead like

```
<div style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me - using display:none still leaves a blank space.

Answer (score 41):

Toggling `display` does not allow for smooth CSS transitions. Instead toggle both the `visibility` and the `max-height`.

```
visibility: hidden;
max-height: 0;
```

Comment: This is useful when you working with animations. Because we are hiding the element outside visible area using something like `transform: translateX(-100%)`. 
We do not want `display: none`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it does not remove from the DOM, as requested.

Answer (score 30):

To use `display:none` is a good option just to removing an element BUT it will be **also removed for screenreaders**. There are also discussions if it effects SEO. There's a good, short article on that topic [on A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/now-you-see-me)

If you really just want **hide** and **not remove** an element, better use:

```
div {
  position: absolute; 
  left: -999em;
}
```

Like this it can be also read by screen readers.

The only disadvantage of this method is, that this DIV is actually rendered and it might effect the **performance**, especially on mobile phones.

Comment: if you choose to position something absolute you can in most cases run with `visibility: hidden;`, lets say you have other absolute elements they will not have a conflict for the space, just conflict of `z-index`. Just for hiding an element I would go with `visibility`

Answer (score 29):

Look, instead of using `visibility: hidden;` use `display: none;`. The first option will hide but **still** takes space and the second option will hide and **doesn't** take any space.

Answer (score 13):

> **display: none** is solution, That's completely hides elements with its space.

#### Story about [`display:none`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) and [`visibility: hidden`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

**`visibility:hidden`** means the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page.

**`display:none`** means completely hides elements with its space. (although you can still interact with it through the DOM)

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this question is saying to use display:none and display:block, but this does not help for someone who is trying to use css transitions to show and hide content using the visibility property.

This also drove me crazy, because using display kills any css transitions.

One solution is to add this to the class that's using visibility:

```
overflow:hidden
```

For this to work is does depend on the layout, but it should keep the empty content within the div it resides in.

Comment: If you play with visibility:hidden and visibility:visible and set your element position:fixed you won't have that problem, it's like magic

Answer (score 5):

`display:none` to hide and set `display:block` to show.

Comment: He asks about removing it visually, "as though they are not in the DOM". Not about removing them from the actual DOM.

Comment: question states not to remove them from the DOM only to make them disappear. `as though they are not in the DOM at all (but without actually removing them from the DOM)`

Comment: @pranay: `visibility: hidden` only stops the display of content but still uses vertical/horizontal space, display:none removes the vertical/horizontal space for the element.

Comment: No it doesn't. 

visibility: hidden; makes the element invisible, but it still takes up space. display: none; makes the document behave as if it was never there.

Answer (score 2):

here's a different take on putting them back after display:none. don't use  display:block/inline etc. Instead (if using javascript) set css property display to '' (i.e. blank)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this question. I wanted the exact opposite, i.e a hidden div should still occupy its space on the browser. So, I used `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#abc').css({"display":"none"});
```

this hides the content and also does not leave empty space.

Answer (score 1):

above my knowledge it is possible in 4 ways

1. HTML`<button style="display:none;"></button>`
2. CSS `#buttonId{ display:none; }`
3. jQuery `$('#buttonId').prop('display':'none');` &  `$("#buttonId").css('opacity', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

***display:none*** is the best thing to avoid takeup white space on the page

Comment: Seems to be just a repeat of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

As I have been troubleshooting this issue and researching, I thought I'd share my insight. If you've gotten yourself to this page, I assume you are trying to figure out why your element is taking up space on your page even with style.display = "none".

**Most likely, the reason for this is NOT the element in question; but a child, parent, or sibling of it**. Open up your console and go to the Elements tab. Look in there for clues as to what could possibly be taking up space. Maybe you're using a template-engine and didn't realize a `<br>` was rendering outside of a dynamic `<div>`. Or maybe you should be targeting a more nested element. Try to think along these lines while troubleshooting.

Comment: Brilliant! I was hiding an item in a list but I overlooked the fact that each item in the list was followed by a <br>.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow all the other options to hide an element do not suit you, there is another option which I do not see mentioned. **It works assuming the element has no children.**

It will hide an element without occupying space:

```
display: contents;
```

Check the browser support as it is a newish CSS feature.

Answer (score 0):

With visibility set to hidden the only way I know of to make it not take up space is to use `position:absolute` and then set the top, left, etc., parameters. It's not ideal but it works.

Answer (score -1):

if display: none; doesn't work you have to add clear: none;