# Hidden divs taking up space

Tags: html, hidden

I've set up all my navigation for my website as hide.show divs (using behaviours).
It all works pretty well, but I've now realised the problem of the divs taking up space even when they're hidden, extending the height of my wrapper far too much.

I really want the height to extend and contract according to the amount of content on display.

http://shanuea.lockernerd.co.uk/camel/

The divs are absolutely positioned and set to visibility:hidden.
Any help appreciated, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide elements without having them take space on the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928688/how-to-hide-elements-without-having-them-take-space-on-the-page)

Comment: You should mark @Stefans answer as correct =)

Answer (score 43):

Use display:none instead of visibility:hidden if you want the divs to take up no space when they are not displayed.

Comment: I'm using `display:none !important; ` in a @print media query to hide the nav but its leaving a big empty space on the left of the page (its a vertical menu on left). Any idea to check for?

Comment: Maybe it's not caused by the nav but something else?

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555185/setting-displaynone-div-inside-div-still-takes-up-space/18555232#comment29909071_18555232 and was able to get it working with `div.content { width: auto; }`

Answer (score 7):

Just a reminder to future googlers:
I had some `<span>` tags which I wanted to hide from visitors.  Behind each `<span>` was a `<br>`.  The `<br>` tags made it look like the `<span>` tags were still taking up space after setting their `display` property to `none`.

Comment: This was the problem for me: those `<br/>` tags that I forgot. My solution was to change my `<span>` to a `<div>` so that it automatically has `display: block`.