# Setting display:none div inside div still takes up space

Tags: html, css

I have a main div contains two divs (one for heading and other for content). the main div is placed at the bottom of the html page with absolute positioning. When I hide content div, it sill takes up space in the bottom of the page.

I need to show only the header div to do a jquery toggle..

```
<div class="tll">
    <div class="tllH">

    </div>
    <div class="tllC">

    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .tll{
        background: yellow;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .tllH{
        background: green;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tllC{
        background: magenta;
        height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting .tll{height: auto} fixed the issue!

Comment: Thanks, just made use of this answer to fix my own print stylesheet. `div.content { width: auto; }` was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For `.tll`, you set a height of `100px`.

`.tllH` is only `20px` and coincidentally `.tllC` is `80px`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `height` of main container is fixed,The solution is present in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/yrMnh/1/).

Comment: Yes.. That was the issue, setting height or main div as auto solved the issue!