# How To Hide an HTML object in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

i want know if there is a way to hide html objects in jsp..for e.g., i have a homepage with login and register button in my jsp app.I want to hide them after successful login.

here is the of screenshot of my homepage
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxVkX.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide elements without having them take space on the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928688/how-to-hide-elements-without-having-them-take-space-on-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many of ways you can implement that.Couple of them would be

1. If you are reloading the whole page when user has successfully logged in, you can use JSTL to selectively render components.

ie, something like below.

```
  <c:if test="if_user_has_not_logged_in">
       <!-- HTML code for login and register button goes here-->
  </c:if>
```

2. you can hide html components using simple Javascript as well By setting Style-> display as none. something like below

   ```
     //You invoke this code when user is logged in
     if('successfully_logged_in') {
      document.getElementById("divIdGoesHere").style.display = "none";
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide html object you can select object with id or class for example, and use `.hide()`;

For example:

```
$("#some-id").hide();
$(".some-id").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have two elements a `checkbox` ( *with `id` and `class` nmed `c_box`* ), and a text item ( *with `id` and `class` named `txt1`* ).

Then the following *JQuery* code may be used to `show`/`hide` *`txt1`* whenever `unchecked` / `checked` :

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.c_box').click(function(){                
        if (document.getElementById('c_box').checked) {    
          $('.txt1').hide();          
        }
        else
        { 
          $('.txt1').show();                  
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id ="c_box" class="c_box"></input>
    
<input type="text" id ="txt1" class="txt1" value="M y  t e x t"></input>

</body>
</html>
```