# Hiding elements using jquery taking up space on page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am doing show and hide of server controls i.e Textboxe and DropDownList using jquery.

Show and hide is working fine but the element which is hidden is taking up its blank space on the page .

I've tried following tricks to hide the elements after using jquery hide() function:

**css('visibility', 'hidden')**

**css('display', 'none')**

as defined in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928688/how-to-hide-elements-without-having-them-take-space-on-the-page)

But still the same problem .

Here is my code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    var col_name= $(this).data('col_name');
    var tbl_name = $(this).data('tbl_name');
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tdRecords = $(tr).children();
    var CurrValue = $(tdRecords[0]).text();
    $('#<%= txt_Curr_Val.ClientID %>').val(CurrValue);
    $('#<%=txt_colname.ClientID%>').val(col_name);
    $('#<%=txt_tblname.ClientID%>').val(tbl_name);
        if (col_name == 'relig_code')
        {
            $('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').show('slow');
            //$('#<%=txt_New_Val.ClientID%>').hide('slow');
            $('#<%=txt_New_Val.ClientID%>').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        }
        else
        {
            //$('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').hide('slow');
            $('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').css('visibility', 'hidden')
             $('#<%=txt_New_Val.ClientID%>').show('slow')
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              Current Value :
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle txtwidth"  runat="server" ID="txt_Curr_Val" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              New Value :
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle txtwidth" runat="server" ID="txt_New_Val" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
                              <asp:DropDownList  runat="server" ID="ddl_relig"></asp:DropDownList><br />
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="txt_tblname" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                              <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle" runat="server" ID="txt_colname"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                       
                    </div>
```

After trying **display : none**

its look like :

[image]

How can I resolve this ?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: `display: none` meets your exact requirement. Can you explain why it does not work for you.

Comment: @PaulZahra I've already defined in my question that i've tried the answer of the question you pointed

Comment: There must be some other css that's making it display... in most browsers 'developer mode' look at the css for the element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan display:none is working but the element is taking up its space on the page

Comment: @AlinaAnjum I can guarantee you that it isn't. If there's a space appearing it's not due to the hidden element. We need to see a working example of your code to help you.

Comment: okay @RoryMcCrossan i just add the snapshot wait

Comment: What is occupying the space? Is there some other (empty) element that is causing the space to remain even when the display of the element in set to `none`?

Comment: Retracted close vote... setup a fiddle for us... https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @AlinaAnjum What is the css for txtstyle txtwidth ?

Comment: @PaulZahra here it is : .txtstyle {
line-height:normal !important;
}
.txtwidth {
width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the presence of line breaks (`<br/>`) between the controls. You can replace them by a class style where you set the display mode to `block`:

```
.newLine
{
    display: block;
}
```

The `newLine` class is applied to each element:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle txtwidth newLine" runat="server" ID="txt_New_Val" TextMode="MultiLine" />
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="newLine" runat="server" ID="ddl_relig" />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle newLine" runat="server" ID="txt_tblname" />
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtstyle newLine" runat="server" ID="txt_colname" />
</div>
```

The `show` and `hide` jQuery functions can then be used and will not leave an extra space between the controls:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    ...
    if (col_name == 'relig_code') {
        $('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').show('slow');
        $('#<%=txt_New_Val.ClientID%>').hide('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').hide('slow');
        $('#<%=txt_New_Val.ClientID%>').show('slow')
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much , it was just a blunder.. Thanks a lot..it worked

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').css('position', 'absolute')
$('#<%=ddl_relig.ClientID%>').css('left', '-9999px')
```

Comment: `opacity: 0` means the element will still take up space in the DOM. `display: none` is exactly what the OP needs, so there is an underlying issue here.