# Hide Element but Preserve for Screen Readers (can't use display:none, visibility:hidden, or opacity:0)

Tags: html, css, screen-readers, section508, nvda

I have an audio-element in my HTML whose only purpose is to make an announcement to blind users via a Screen Reader. It's a DIV, but it's invisible to regular users.

The way to announce something is by creating an element with `role=alert` (no other way to do it, there's no JS function to directly "speak" to a reader, for example):

```
<!-- This element can be dynamically added OR shown (via JS) to make a Screen Reader announcement -->
<div role="alert">This will be announced to Screen Readers.</div>
```

However, I can't have this "audio assistant" element be visible to regular users.

1) Can't use `display: none`; -> the Screen Reader won't pick it up

2) Can't use `visibility: hidden;` -> the Screen Reader won't pick it up

3) Can't use `opacity: 0;` -> because space is taken up, layout must be exactly the same

I found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25339638/1005607

`div {
  position: absolute; 
  left: -999em;
}`

This works great, it solves my problem. But it's a bit of a hack. I wanted to ask: Is there a better, more standard way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a "better" way, but this will hide it in place.

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:0;
  width:0;
}
```

Comment: that's not a complete answer.  setting only those properties will not fully hide the element on all browsers and all screen readers

Answer (score 2):

It's a common practice to use CSS to visually hide an element but allow it to be discoverable by screen reader users.  It's not necessarily considered a "hack".

There are more CSS properties needed than what you tried.  See [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3) for details.

Also, you can search for the "visually-hidden" class.

Both `sr-only` and `visually-hidden` are common names used to name the class that visually hides elements.

Also, your understanding of [`role="alert"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#alert) isn't quite accurate.

> The way to announce something is by creating an element with role=alert (no other way to do it, there's no JS function to directly "speak" to a reader, for example):

`role="alert"` has an implicit [`aria-live="assertive"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live).  Elements with `aria-live` will announce **changes** to that element to screen readers.  It will not automatically announce that element.  For example,

```
<div id="foo" aria-live="polite"></div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = 'hello'">update</button>
```

When I click on the button, text will be injected into the <div> and the new text will be announced.

In general, you want to use `aria-live="polite"` and not `aria-live="assertive"`.  When you use `role="alert"`, you get `aria-live="assertive"`.

So if your page is updating its contents, then using `aria-live` is the right thing to do.  But it does not cause something to be announced just because your page loaded.

The screen reader user has many ways to navigate a website using quick navigation keys defined in the screen reader (such as <kbd>H</kbd> to go to the next heading [h1, h2, h3, etc], or <kbd>T</kbd> to go to the next table, or <kbd>L</kbd> to go to the next list, etc.), provided your HTML is using semantic elements (such as <h1>, <table>, <ul>, etc).  If you have text that is hidden to sighted users, then that text can be found by screen reader users without you forcing it to be read automatically.