# Angular template, remove div and white space (div is removed, but not white space)

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-template

**Edit:
After more thoughts, i am removing the unnecessary element within the TS file and making my template file do less work.**

I've looked at a few stack o/f threads about removing a div and the white space that it takes. Such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928688/how-to-hide-elements-without-having-them-take-space-on-the-page)

The div is hidden, however the white space is still there on my template.

code

```
<div *ngIf="array[i] !== null; else hideDivAndRemoveWhiteSpace">
  //business logic
</div>
<ng-template #hideDivAndRemoveWhiteSpace>
  //this template should be hidden
  <div class="hide-div"></div>
</ng-template>
```

css

```
.hide-div {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values you want to exclude are actually `null` specifically (and not, for instance, `undefined`)? `*ngIf` should be sufficient on its own for this, you shouldn't need to substitute a blank template.

Comment: they are null, like i said the values are hidden (meaning the else portion of my if logic runs) but white space remains.

Comment: `*ngIf` removes the element entirely if it's false, so if that's failing and you're sure the data is correct the problem might be higher up in the DOM hierarchy. Can you add more of the surrounding HTML?

Comment: @john, yes the data is correct. I think the issue is ng-template, it still puts the removed element on the DOM. As someone mentioned below, use ng-container instread. However, for now, I've resolved my issue by removing the element in my TS file and make my template do less work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<ng-container> </ng-container>`

See Angular's documentation about ng-container how Angular doesn't add it to the DOM

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Also, see this answer:

[<ng-container> vs <template>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547858/ng-container-vs-template)

Answer (score 0):

Which whitespace are tlaking about ?

In your code, why wouldn't you just do:

```
<div *ngIf="array['data']">
    //business logic
</div>
```

without the "ele" and the "ng-template"

Comment: the array has question/answers. right now I am rendering all the question even if they have no answer. The goal is to render only questions with answers and hide the questions w/o answer. What you've suggested is how my template is rendering right now.

Comment: Then this is what you have to check in your ngIf: <div *ngIf="{{question with answer}}">

Answer (score 0):

you may add this option to the component decorator `preserveWhitespaces: false`

this will remove the elemnt from the dom

```
<div *ngIf="false" >
..
</div>
```

> false mean any falsy value

add class base on condtions

style.css

```
.d-none {
 display:none
}
```

template

```
<div [ngClass]="{'d-none': true}">
...
</div>
```

or you can use `ng-container` so you don't need to wrap you business logic with any div elemnt

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">
 //business logic
</ng-container>
```

> if `condition`true the container business logic elements will be visible if it false nothing will render to the dom