# Hide and show buttons in same place on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my `page.php` I have 3 buttons :

```
<input type="submit" value="Btn 1"  id="btn1">   
<input type="submit" value="Btn 2" id="btn2" onClick="action();>  
<input type="submit" value="Btn 3" id="btn3" onClick="action();>
```

first `Btn 1` button hidden with load:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

with click on `Btn 2` or `Btn 3` I want hide `Btn 2` or `Btn 3` and show `Btn 1`:

```
var hidden = false;
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('btn3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } 
    }
```

this way hidden button `Btn 1` leaves empty space in place where it was visible, or if I put it below `Btn 2` and `Btn 3` then I got two empty spaces in places of `Btn 2` and `Btn 3`.

How it is possible show and hide buttons in same place on `html` page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide elements without having them take space on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928688/how-to-hide-elements-without-having-them-take-space-on-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below using `display:none;`

[difference between visibility:hidden and display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone/133064)

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

function action(el) {
  el.classList.add('hide');
  btn1.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="hide" value="Btn 1" id="btn1">
<input type="submit" value="Btn 2" id="btn2" onClick="action(this);">
<input type="submit" value="Btn 3" id="btn3" onClick="action(this);">
```

Comment: Hello, so I can do it this way   document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'none';